# Taylor's theorem for embedded manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, power-series

For an embedded Riemannian manifold $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and a point $x \in M$, there is a series expansion (page 8 of [Monera's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5971)):
$$\exp_x(t v) = x +  t J_x(v) + \frac{t^2}{2!} Q_x(v) + \cdots$$
where $v \in T_x M$ satisfies $\|v\|=1$, $t \ge 0$, $u \mapsto x + J_x(u)$ is the (linear) embedding of the tangent space $T_x M$, and $Q_x(v) = (\nabla_v v)^\perp$, the component of $\nabla_v v$ that is normal to $T_x M$.

> **Question.** Is the following or a variant of it true? For some constant $C$, we have that whenever $0 < t < C$, there is a vector $w
> > \in T_x M$ with $\|w \|\le 1$ such that: $$\exp_x(tv) = x + t J_x(v) +
> \frac{t^2}{2!} Q_x(w)$$ A higher order (more than quadratic) analogue
> is also sought, if it exists.

My end goal of this analysis is to obtain a bound on the local deviation of an embedded manifold from being linear. Namely, upon accepting the claimed result, we have that
$$\| \exp_x(tv) - (x + t J_x(v)) \| \le \frac{A}{2}\cdot t^2 \text{ where } A := \sup_{w \in TM, \|w \| \le 1 } (\nabla_w w)^\perp $$

And honestly, all this feels like they are likely to be some exercise problems to a Riemannian geometry course, but I can't find a reference for this type of result. Pointing towards a classical reference for this would be highly welcome as well.

Comment: Your notation does not make sense to me.  What does the inequality mean between a point of $M$ and the function on the right, which appears to be vector-valued?

Comment: ah, someone added a typo while editing. I'm going to delete that $>$.

Comment: I think I have a resolution to the question asked, by applying Taylor's theorem coordinate-wise to the exponential map $t \mapsto \exp_x(tv)$ and bounding the error term crudely. This seems to yield that the error term is bounded by $Bt^2$ where $B = \frac n2 \sup_{w \in TM} \| \nabla_w w \| $ and $n$ is the ambient dimension. I'll clarify after I get some sleep.

Comment: Your question looks essentially like the definition of the Taylor expansion of 1st order.  So, provided I'm not misunderstanding your question, the answer is yes.  Moreover, J_x(v)=v for any reasonable definition of the tangent space.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. My question is on whether the error term of the 1st order Taylor expansion of $\exp_x$ can be realized as $(t^2/2) Q_x(w)$ for some appropriate $w \in T_x M$ with $\|w\| \le 1$. I don't think that this follows directly from Taylor's theorem? The best shot seems to be applying Taylor's theorem coordinate-wise to $t \mapsto \exp_x(tv)$ but that won't imply the desired result directly.
Also, $J_x: T_x M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a required notation if we regard the tangent space as not a priori embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Proposition 1.2.8 of https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/126302/eth-49463-02.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y seems related.